# Get a Variable value in build time

Tags: c#

I m confused how can i set my static variable value in the build time so that it will be set only once for that application not only in run-time .

a quick example why would i want that : 

Lets say i have a Server Application Receive Data From Clients Indirectly (refering to an SQL Database) , So the Client send the data to the table and The Server Retreive those data from the Table . So i need an `UserID` to specify where the data come from , cause The Server Application can be used by alot of Users at the same Time .

My question is how can i achieve that ?

**Please note that the Client Don't need a Connection or an account he only Send data to the Table with the Server UserID**
example :

```
Send(Data,UserID)// Method to insert data in a table
```

**Cause basically there is Only one Database and One Table to Store the data for Both the whole Clients And Servers**

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you need a ID value for each Client, then you can declare: `static readonly string UserId = "MyStaticId";`

Comment: I can't obviously do that since the User will send the Client Application with his own ID , so foreach user register to set his own server he'll need his own client application with his own specified account ID =)

Comment: I'm *also* confused. It's entirely unclear as to what you're asking or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you saying you want to give a different build to each client, and each build would be custom for that client and have their client id embedded in that particular build?

Comment: To make it Simple , When the Client want to Store Data in Database he need to store it with The `SERVER USER ID` , BECAUSE the server will have multiple users so i don't want to the other users to see the data from the clients that they arent their clients

Comment: Client will need a connection to send data to the table.   So not clear.  VTC

Comment: @aquinas Exactly =)

Comment: @ Paparazzi Yes he will have the SQL database Credentials to store data there , i just need custom build foreach client

Comment: Why don't you write an API for the user to hit instead? You can put the user info in the config file if you want. What you're doing sounds like a terrible idea for many reasons.

Comment: You mean "compile for each customer" and send it to them? It sounds like that.

Comment: @Joe Philllips Yes It is so for that i need to solve that , and for the config file how can i do that cause if i embedded the config file it while be unable to change or modify on it so how can i embeded programmaticaly

Comment: @Toris something like that !

Comment: I agree with @JoePhilllips . Furthermore, you need to store the credentials you're giving away so you will allow only authorized users to send data to the server and in the future you can remove a user just changing the server side.

Comment: If you want something like unique key in db, check "Guid". It's not a build time value but nearly unique.

Comment: @Toris But how can i set that value in the application once in the build-time

Comment: @peval27 authorized Clients* There is a Different between user and client in this case The users is the ones who control his own SERVER and the Client is the Clients how send data to that Server and the user of that server is the one who will be able to see that

Comment: Not build time but "Unique value for each user" and "Set to DB at first connection" you want?

Comment: that Unique Value will be in the Both Sides so that it means the data sent from the client is for that specific user no one can see it but that user Cause basically there is  Only one Database and One Table to Store the data for the Both Clients And Servers

Comment: "Generate Guid at first boot of app" is nearly same as "Build time value" I think.

Comment: @Toris You didnt fully get what i want exactly i guess ><

Comment: So... you need "build with different values" and "put them on the server and can download the app only once" logic.

Comment: Yes but Will be the opposite Build The Client with The Server Value (Cause the User who use the server is the one who gonna build the Client )

Comment: @Buffer_z It's not the neatest way, but you can use an app.config file and check whether the GUID is present during startup, othewise generate it and store in app.config. The second time the app will run, the GUID will be the same.

Comment: YES but that app.config i need it to be Embedded and if its embedded i can't obviously make change on it cause i want the client side to be only an one .exe file that doesnt need an extern files

Comment: 1. Auto generate some value for each access (and put it to a file or db). 2.Use the value to build for each customer with auto-build system.

Comment: Some online build system may help as a sample.

Comment: @Toris auto-build system. ==> Got an example ?

Comment: Searching... Try keywords like "github webhook auto build" or "code sandbox"

Comment: @Toris okay i'll try it thanks sir !

Comment: Your welcome. And easier way.(If request count is not so heavy) 1.Use pre-build task to generate random value (and put it to a file) 2.Use the file as a source of value and build. (several times, enough for requests) 3.Store them to server and so on.

Comment: @Toris Yes! Please put your comment as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124747/discussion-between-toris-and-buffer-z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use pre-build task to generate random value (and put it to a file)

2.Use the file as a source of value and build. (several times, enough for requests)

3.Store them to your server and so on.